How can I find the scaling factor of this current transformer?
I am working on a project to measure AC RMS current using a microcontroller. For this I am using a current transformer (CT) with an unknown ratio. I took some readings by putting a load on the primary side and measuring the output voltage. The output voltage has an offset of 2.5V
I wrote a routine to calculate the RMS current. Previously I read the AC RMS voltage. The routine is almost same except for the scaling factor.
What is the ratio of this current transformer? I will add this ratio in the program to actual load value. Following is the circuit diagram and reading which I have taken.

The waveform I am getting:


following are the waveforms taken at different load and yes they are clipping. but what is the reason of clipping?



Any guess on 1st , 2nd step?

How does Va get 2.6V connected to 5V? what reference? The node without a label?

How distorted is the sine? Do you have a true RMS meter?  Do you not see errors in your calibration/readings?

Va is at 5V. Vout which i didn't mentioned is 100k----Vout----100k----Gnd
At this Vout point I am getting 2.6V dc shifted waveform

how did you measure each result with poor SNR? Why this bad way to insert 2.5Vdc on an AC signal attenuated 50%

At 2.6A primary you’re getting 0.51Vrms secondary, if I understand your figures correctly.  With a load of 100R the secondary current will be 5.1mA, which gives you the ratio.  As you’ve drawn the circuit, the divider halves both the 5V supply and the signal.  Would you be better off feeding the 2.5V from the divider into one side of the CT and measuring the signal on the other side?

Would you be better off feeding the 2.5V from the divider into one side of the CT and measuring the signal on the other side?
what would be the effect of this overall?

It would avoid running DC current through the CT which may bias the core and distort your readings if it gets close to saturation.

@Transistor you definitely be right. That raise question in my mind. The resistance R2 and R3 are big like 100k. The DC current will be in uA. Can this Ampere saturate the core of transformer? I don't know much so you guys tell me this

Once you know the ratio of the CT, the maximum secondary current will be the primary current divided by the ratio.  Provided the DC current is much less than the maximum operating current there shouldn’t be a problem.

@Abdul to answer your question, the arrangement you’ve drawn will attenuate the AC as well as the DC so Vout will show only 50% of the signal coming from the CT.  If you feed 2.5V into one side and measure the other side of the CT you’ll see 100% of the AC signal

Yes I see the waveforms after increasing the load and they are not clipping as I increase the load. But I don't get the point that Vout will show only 50% of the signal coming from CT. Kindly explain me. What I am getting is that when we dc offset the signal to the power supply (in this case 5V) then above this voltage everything will be clipped but at how much voltage this clipping will start?. I have uploaded the 2 pictures in which waveforms at 1A and at 4.5Amp are observed. low ampere is not clipping because the amplitude is small but the 4.5Amp waveform clips due to greater amplitude

sorry. I just type not clipping. actually its clipping

@Abdul I would imagine that the CT is saturating.  Do you know it’s current rating?

@Abdul regarding the 50% attenuation: as you have drawn the circuit, the divider will divide both the DC offset and the AC signal by 2.  If you put the divider on one side of the CT (effectively biasing at to 2.5V then on the other side of the CT you’ll will see 100% of the AC signal.  It’s up to you whether you would prefer to have a larger or smaller signal though.

@Frog No I don't know about the current rating of this CT

@Frog Got your point regarding 50% attenuation. Can you tell me how much clipping will be done when I increase the load by calculations

@Abdul if the CT is clipping then you’re overloading it, you should find a CT that’s rated for the current you need.  Once you reach saturation there will be little output change with increased current and you risk overheating the device.

The tabulated primary currents versus the tabulated multimeter output readings are a calibration; do a line fit to determine the scale factor.
That factor might depend on the particulars of the multimeter, of course.
added by D.A.S.
A spreadsheet can give the coefficients to a curve fit and convert pk.to rms.

